# Sum until value reached then stop

Tags: excel

I have honestly and sincerely gone through a good number of questions regarding this topic, but none seem to exactly hit the mark for my issue (due to my lack of knowledge, obviously).

In any case, I work in insurance and currently working on a program with a loss aggregate limit of USD 10 mln in the year. So the table on the left in the attached snapshot shows the incidents(losses) during that day of the month (going down) during that year (going across). What I would like to do in the table on the right is to tell it to sum losses until USD 10 mln is reached then set all remaining losses for the remainder of the year to zero (I have months in consecutive order with subtotals for the months in between).

To be clearer, for example, January 11th, 2017 should read USD 9,772,760 since there was a USD 227,240 loss on January 1st, 2017 (combined would be USD 10 mln) and therefore would exclude the January 26th loss of USD 222,582 or any following losses for the rest of the year (set to 0).

Hope I'm clear, and I hope I'm not breaking any protocols by posting this as is. 
[image]

[Example no.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgFQt.jpg)

Comment: I couldn't see the image cause blocked, but could you do this with an If statement? " IF(SUM($A$1:A1)>10000000, 0, A1) ". you could also use SUMIFS if the subtotals are in the way

Comment: Thanks, Bobby. I have tried everything I possibly know about SUM and SUMIFS, I've tried to add multiple IF(AND and IF(OR combinations, but the problem is a logical one. If A1 A2 and A3 equal 5, 10, and 5, the formula should say A1 = 5, A2 = 5, A3 = 0 (because the threshold is set at 10). And that's for one month only, I got 11 other months to do that. Obviously, I dare not do anything manual because the data is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I got this right...

I created two formulas - one for row 3 (first value of the month):

```
=IF(E3>10000000,10000000,E3)
```

...and the remaining days (rows 4 & below):

```
=IF(E$2>10000000,IF(SUM(K$3:K3)>=10000000,0,IF(SUM(E$3:E4)>10000000,E4-SUM(E$3:E3),E4)),E4)
```

Both are highlighted with yellow color. Here's the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Justyna. Your formula works perfectly; I have also found a different (and longer) formula that gets the job done for January, but the problem remains for August (your formula included). Seems my nightmare will begin since it is clear that I have to go with VBA!

Comment: Uh-oh. What happens in August? Want to share a screenshot?

Comment: Just added another snapshot named 'Example no.2' on original post (as a link, don't have reputation score yet to embed!) - in the example which mimics the larger set of data but a much smaller scale, the formula doesn't take into account the previous months totals (which I fixed). However, where it should give me the remainder of $95, it seems to be calculating something else (circled).

Comment: Abdul, thanks for posting! The structure is a little bit unfriendly as there is sum calculated for each month (rows 5, 9, 13). I replaced these with blanks to have a continuous formula which can be used for the whole column E, I hope that's okay. Use `=IF(ISNUMBER(B6),IF(SUMPRODUCT($C$5:C6,--ISNUMBER($B$5:B6))>$C$2,$C$2-SUM($E$5:E5),C6),"")` in cell `E5` and drag it down, here's the result: https://i.imgur.com/UoxD1dj.png

Comment: You are nothing short of a logical genius. I've known that there is at least one element, if removed, would make the whole thing work. Never suspected it would be the subtotals. Many thanks for your help!